Is it okay to make a nested ConsumerStatefulWidget?
Is it okay to make a nested ConsumerStatefulWidget in a single screen? Each ConsumerStatefulWidget has ref.watch(someAsyncNotifierProvider) in it.

What do you mean by "okay"? Do you mean will it compile?

It’s perfectly acceptable. The key is to watch providers only where necessary, ensuring efficient state management.
To optimize rebuilds, you can:

Create providers that expose only specific aspects of the state your widget depends on.
Use Consumer to rebuild only certain child widgets when the provider’s value changes.
If you’re using hooks, select can be very useful for conditional rebuilding.

